# how to get woocommerce product information outside loop in custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

how to get a product by id outside the loop

this is my function:

```
function rakhsh_product_info($id){
    $result = get_product( $id );
    die($result);
}
```

get `Call to undefined function get_product()` error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if ( function_exists( 'get_product' ) ) {
    $result = get_product( $id );
  } else {
    $result = new WC_Product( $id );
  }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it says `Fatal error: Class 'WC_Product' not found`

Comment: You need to make sure you are calling your function *after* WooCommerce has loaded. See the answer from @Danijel for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All of these errors indicate that your plugin is loaded before Woocommerce. Place the calls to woocommerce functions at least in [plugins_loaded](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded) action or later. Example from [wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/):

```
<?php
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_override' );

function my_plugin_override() {
    // your code here
}
?>
```

Check [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for list of available action hooks and action execution order.